# Move hours played back to where it was

Tags: steam

In the new update, they moved "Hours played" and "Last played" stats to the right column in the Library Detail View.

Is there a way I can move it back to where it was?  To help illustrate, here is a picture:

[image: Detail View]

I am wanting to take the states in the RED box and move them back where they were (GREEN box).

Client information is:
Build - Sep 10 2013, 18:49:55
API - v012
Package versions - 1378937703 / 1378937703

**Unnecessary information**

For those of you interested in why, here it is.  I have 2 monitors.  One is 1920x1080 (main), the other 1366x768 (side).  The main monitor is directly in front of me when at my desk.  Therefore, the side monitor is entirely to the right of me, stretching way over to the edge of my desk.

When the stats were next to the play button, they were easy to read and right in the center of the screen.  Now they are even further from me and my lazy eyes don't like it.

Why does any of that matter?  Well I use these stats to determine which games I have yet to play (buying Humble Bundles really crowds up my list and it can get hard to keep track of which games I have yet to start up).  This also makes it easy for me to pick a game to play when I don't know what I want to play.  Sort of a "I haven't played Castle crashers in a long time" or "I only have 3 hours in FFVII? I should go play that!" line of thinking.

Comment: I believe these can be changed by editing the skin, but the details are beyond my experience.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yea same here. I looked for a skin for this but I think it might be too new a thing to search for.  I might have to look into making one myself.

Comment: The stats are under the game title, next to the play button for me. Was this a change that was already reverted?